# How to color a group of labels or branches in heatmap.2 in R

Tags: r

By using the data from `?heatmap.2`:

```
data(mtcars)
x<-scale(mtcars)


set.seed(123)
tf<-sample(rownames(x), 5)
tf

[1] "Merc 280"         "Pontiac Firebird" "Merc 450SL"  
 "Fiat X1-9"        "Porsche 914-2" 

heatmap.2(x)
```

what I wanted is to color row names in `tf` (on the right) in red or the branches of these names (on the left) in red color (or both in red will be greater). I dug around and can't find the solutions. Does anybody have suggestions using the above sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to colour the row names in red you need to do the following:

```
data(mtcars)
x<-scale(mtcars)

set.seed(123)
tf<-sample(rownames(x), 5)
```

Create a vector cols with the colours of the row names. Red for tf and Black anywhere else

```
#initiate cols with all black
cols <- rep('black', nrow(mtcars))
#turn red the specified rows in tf
cols[row.names(mtcars) %in% tf] <- 'red'
```

Now plot using the `colRow` argument:

```
heatmap.2(x, colRow = cols)
```

Output:

[image]

As for colouring the dentrogram, I don't think there is an option to do this in `heatmap.2`. There seems to be a way with the `Heatplus` package and function `annHeatmap2` but I have no experience in using this. There is an example [here](http://www.molecularecologist.com/2013/08/making-heatmaps-with-r-for-microbiome-analysis/) if you are interested in exploring new packages.